# Problem with Python code for finding factorials

Tags: python, python-3.x

Have the function `FirstFactorial(num)` take the num parameter being passed and return the factorial of it. For example: if num = 4, then your program should return (4 * 3 * 2 * 1) = 24. For the test cases, the range will be between 1 and 18 and the input will always be an integer.

and this is my code

```
def FirstFactorial(num):
    x = [1]
    if num == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        for i in range(1,num+1):
            x = x*(i)
    return x

print (FirstFactorial(4))
```

The expected output is `24`. I get the following output from the code given above.

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Why `x = [1]` rather than `x = 1`? Factorials are not lists.

Comment: What is the output of your code?

Comment: @moreON should be a very long list of 1s

Comment: @JohnColeman - sure would be, but surely it's nice to encourage people to include actual output in their questions?

Comment: @moreON Good point

Comment: sorry for not writing the output

Comment: so why does x can't be a list and the new number be added to the 1 I saved in

Comment: Here are [the instructions for this skills assessment (demo) test](https://www.coderbyte.com/editor/FirstE%20Factorial:JavaScript).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's make a better code:

```py
def factorial(num):
    f = 1
    for i in range(1, num+1):
        f = f * i
    return f
```

Some parts of your code have no sense at all, for example, `x = [1]` declares `x` equals a list with one element one. Then if you make `list * number` in python you multiply the list:

```py
x = [1, 2]
x = x * 2
print(x) # prints [1, 2, 1, 2]
```

The if statement that checks if the number is 1 is not necessary using the code above.

Comment: @MarcoMaher mark the answer as the correct one :) nice to know i helped

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
import math
print(math.factorial(4))
```

output:

> 24

Answer (score 0):

You had error in your *x* declaration. Also, using lambda expression.

`fact = lambda n:1 if n==0 else n*fact(n-1)`

`print(fact(4))`

**>>> 24**

> 42 bytes

`fact = lambda x:0**x or x*fact(x-1)`

`print(fact(4))`

> 27 bytes

Python has C type internal implementation of factorial method in *math* module. Since it's C, it's faster than Python's approach.

```
import math

print(math.factorial(4))
```

First answer still has *for* loop,

```
def factorial(n):
    return 1 if ( n == 1 or n == 0 ) else n * factorial(n - 1)
```

Comment: Somewhat baroque (especially for a beginner like OP), plus: `fact(1000)` throws `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

Comment: You can increment stack depth for deeper recursive calls, `sys.setrecursionlimit()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have done a small mistake. Instead of defining the variable `x` as a list (in the first line after the definition of the function `FirstFactorial(num)` , `x=[1]`) , you want do define `x` as a single number, i.e. `x=1`.

In Python, multiplication of a list by a positive scalar (say `n`) leads to repetition of the numbers in the list `n` number of times. In other words, **the * operator repeats a list for the given number of times.** This is what was happening in your code in the line `x = x*(i)`.

You can read more about python lists [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list).

The following code will work fine, and do your job. The only change that I have done is in the first line after the definition of the function `FirstFactorial(num)`.

```
def FirstFactorial(num):
    x = 1
    if num == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        for i in range(1,num+1):
            x = x*(i)   
    return x

print (FirstFactorial(4)) 
>>24
```

Also, you do not need to have a separate `if` statement to define **1!**. The following code is more concise and it will give you factorials of all numbers including 1.

```
def FirstFactorial(num):
    x = 1
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        x = x*(i)   
    return x

print (FirstFactorial(1))
>> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually correct one for me I got this and achieved to given test result.

```
def FirstFactorial(num):
  if num ==1:
    return 1
  else:
    for i in range(1, num-1/2):
       num = num*(i)
  return num

# keep this function call here
```